# Specific pages in activeadmin return a blank page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I have a rails app and since a few hours I get empty pages when accessing some of the locations urls inside activeadmin:

- `/admin`
- `/orders`

In turn all other pages seem to work fine. 
For example:

- `/users`
- `/orders/33` (Order detail)
- `/products`
- `/news`
- `/categories`

This is the HTTP Response for `mydomain.com/admin/orders`:

`HTTP
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
Date: Tue, 03 Oct 2017 22:28:41 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Status: 200 OK
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Cache-Control: no-cache
Set-Cookie: _myapp_session=xyzxyzxyzxyz--30390slslslsl; path=/; HttpOnly
X-Request-Id: 6daa43d1-a683-496f-94e4-09ad9e433e44
X-Runtime: 0.761160
Content-Encoding: gzip
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Proxy-Connection: Keep-alive`

I did try:

- Restart the unicorn server
- Restart nginx
- Delete the `tmp` folder and restart the server
- Tried in both Chrome and Safari
- To inspect the log but nothin shows up there
- Update ActiveAdmin fom 1.0 to 1.1 (Did not work in both cases)
- Update Rails from 4.4.2 to 4.2.10
- Restart the server (the actual machine)

[image]

```
These are my gems

  * actionmailer (4.2.10)
  * actionpack (4.2.10)
  * actionview (4.2.10)
  * activeadmin (1.1.0)
  * activejob (4.2.10)
  * activemodel (4.2.10)
  * activerecord (4.2.10)
  * activesupport (4.2.10)
  * acts_as_tenant (0.4.1)
  * addressable (2.5.2)
  * airbrussh (1.3.0)
  * arbre (1.1.1)
  * arel (6.0.4)
  * autoprefixer-rails (7.1.4.1)
  * babosa (1.0.2)
  * bcrypt (3.1.11)
  * better_errors (2.3.0)
  * binding_of_caller (0.7.2)
  * bootstrap-sass (3.3.7)
  * builder (3.2.3)
  * bundler (1.13.2)
  * byebug (9.1.0)
  * capistrano (3.9.1)
  * capistrano-bundler (1.3.0)
  * capistrano-rails (1.1.8)
  * capistrano-rails-console (2.2.1)
  * capistrano-rvm (0.1.2)
  * capybara (2.10.1)
  * carrierwave (1.2.1 32519e0)
  * choice (0.2.0)
  * chunky_png (1.3.8)
  * cliver (0.3.2)
  * coderay (1.1.2)
  * coffee-rails (4.1.1)
  * coffee-script (2.4.1)
  * coffee-script-source (1.12.2)
  * concurrent-ruby (1.0.5)
  * countries (2.1.2)
  * country_select (3.1.1)
  * crass (1.0.2)
  * daemons (1.2.4)
  * debase (0.2.1)
  * debase-ruby_core_source (0.9.10)
  * debug_inspector (0.0.3)
  * delayed_job (4.1.3)
  * delayed_job_active_record (4.1.2)
  * devise (4.3.0)
  * devise-i18n (1.2.0)
  * dotenv (2.2.1)
  * dotenv-rails (2.2.1)
  * em-websocket (0.5.1)
  * erubi (1.6.1)
  * erubis (2.7.0)
  * eventmachine (1.0.9.1)
  * exception_notification (4.1.4)
  * execjs (2.7.0)
  * faraday (0.13.1)
  * fastimage (2.1.0)
  * ffi (1.9.18)
  * foreman (0.84.0)
  * formatador (0.2.5)
  * formtastic (3.1.4)
  * formtastic_i18n (0.6.0)
  * friendly_id (5.0.5)
  * geocoder (1.4.4)
  * globalid (0.4.0)
  * guard (2.14.1)
  * guard-compat (1.2.1)
  * guard-livereload (2.5.2)
  * has_scope (0.7.1)
  * high_voltage (3.0.0)
  * highline (1.7.8)
  * http_parser.rb (0.6.0)
  * httparty (0.15.6)
  * i18n (0.8.6)
  * i18n_data (0.8.0)
  * inherited_resources (1.7.2)
  * interception (0.5)
  * jbuilder (2.7.0)
  * jquery-rails (4.3.1)
  * jquery-ui-rails (6.0.1)
  * just-datetime-picker (0.0.7)
  * kaminari (1.0.1)
  * kaminari-actionview (1.0.1)
  * kaminari-activerecord (1.0.1)
  * kaminari-core (1.0.1)
  * listen (3.0.6)
  * loofah (2.1.1)
  * lumberjack (1.0.12)
  * mail (2.6.6)
  * mail_form (1.7.0)
  * mailcatcher (0.6.5)
  * method_source (0.9.0)
  * mime-types (3.1)
  * mime-types-data (3.2016.0521)
  * mini_magick (4.8.0)
  * mini_portile2 (2.3.0)
  * minitest (5.10.3)
  * money (6.9.0)
  * multi_json (1.12.2)
  * multi_xml (0.6.0)
  * multipart-post (2.0.0)
  * mysql2 (0.3.21)
  * nenv (0.3.0)
  * net-scp (1.2.1)
  * net-ssh (4.2.0)
  * nokogiri (1.8.1)
  * notiffany (0.1.1)
  * orm_adapter (0.5.0)
  * poltergeist (1.11.0)
  * polyamorous (1.3.1)
  * powder (0.3.2)
  * pry (0.11.1)
  * pry-rails (0.3.6)
  * pry-rescue (1.4.5)
  * public_suffix (3.0.0)
  * pundit (1.1.0)
  * quiet_assets (1.1.0)
  * rack (1.6.8)
  * rack-mini-profiler (0.10.5)
  * rack-protection (1.5.3)
  * rack-test (0.6.3)
  * rails (4.2.10)
  * rails-deprecated_sanitizer (1.0.3)
  * rails-dom-testing (1.0.8)
  * rails-erd (1.5.2)
  * rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.3)
  * rails-i18n (4.0.9)
  * rails_12factor (0.0.3)
  * rails_layout (1.0.41)
  * rails_serve_static_assets (0.0.5)
  * rails_stdout_logging (0.0.5)
  * railties (4.2.10)
  * rake (12.1.0)
  * ransack (1.8.3)
  * rb-fsevent (0.10.2)
  * rb-inotify (0.9.10)
  * redcarpet (3.4.0)
  * request_store (1.3.2)
  * responders (2.4.0)
  * rqrcode (0.10.1)
  * ruby-debug-ide (0.6.0)
  * ruby-graphviz (1.2.3)
  * sass (3.5.2)
  * sass-listen (4.0.0)
  * sass-rails (5.0.6)
  * seed_dump (3.2.4)
  * shellany (0.0.1)
  * simple_form (3.5.0)
  * sinatra (1.4.8)
  * sixarm_ruby_unaccent (1.2.0)
  * skinny (0.2.4)
  * slim (3.0.8)
  * slim-rails (3.1.3)
  * sort_alphabetical (1.1.0)
  * spring (2.0.2)
  * sprockets (3.7.1)
  * sprockets-rails (3.2.1)
  * sqlite3 (1.3.13)
  * sshkit (1.14.0)
  * sshkit-interactive (0.2.3)
  * stripe (3.4.1)
  * temple (0.8.0)
  * thin (1.5.1)
  * thor (0.19.4)
  * thread_safe (0.3.6)
  * tilt (2.0.8)
  * tzinfo (1.2.3)
  * uglifier (3.2.0)
  * unicode_utils (1.4.0)
  * warden (1.2.7)
  * web-console (2.3.0)
  * websocket-driver (0.7.0)
  * websocket-extensions (0.1.2)
  * wicked_pdf (1.1.0)
  * wkhtmltopdf-binary-edge (0.12.4.0)
  * xpath (2.1.0)
```

**Update**: I don't see any thing in the log and when I `tail -f` the log and I reload the blank page, then there is nothing appended to the log.

**Update**: The App runs in `production` environment and I am not able to locally reproduce the problem.

Comment: Assuming you are seeing any errors in the log, can you send the request-query-response sequence log when you load the page ? There isn't enough information in the question.

Comment: @Shaunak, weirdly I don't see anything in the log. The rendering of the page somehow fails silently and as you see in the HTTP header it starts with `HTTP 200` so not an `HTTP 500` like you might expect.

Comment: what is the environment you are running the application, is it prod?

Comment: "certain urls". Be more specific. Is this only index pages?

Comment: @PiersC: I did update my answer. In my case `/orders` is blank and `/admin/` which points to my dashboard. The application runs in `production` environment.

Comment: @Bijendra: The App runs in `production` environment and I am not able to locally reproduce the problem. I did update my question accordingly

Comment: I would guess you have bad/unexpected order data in production.  Review the data directly in MySQL, visit the view pages for each of the orders.  Post  here the orders index definition if practical.

Comment: Thanks @PiersC. I did find the culprit that dis not have an associated object assigned. It's a bit weird that this does not result in an exception, that would show up in the log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess you have bad/unexpected order data in production. Review the data directly in MySQL, visit the view pages for each of the orders. Post here the orders index definition if practical.

Comment: That was exactly the case. So I ran a script to output all of the order detail URLs and opened them in the browser, and there were some of them that were empty too. However, I do wonder, why there is no actual error thrown.

Comment: Well at least now you can reproduce and debug outside production.